# Why does java embedded derby fails to start after working for some time

Tags: java, derby

I'm woking on a java project where I'm using an embedded derby database

During development, I create the database then I make the connection in netbeans  and I use the following code to access and manipulate the database

```
// Get a connection that is connected with the offline database
private static synchronized Connection openLocalDbConnection(){
   
   String connectionString = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/db_name";
   Connection connection = null;
   
   try{
       
         String  driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
         Class.forName(driver);
         
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.put("username", "user");
         props.put("password", "password"); 
         
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,props);
         
   }catch(SQLException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace(); 
       System.err.println("At Opening database SQLException" + ex.getMessage());
       System.err.println("At Opening database " + ex.getErrorCode());
      
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException  e){
       e.printStackTrace();
     
   }
   
   return connection;
}
```

Using this method, I successfully get the connection object and the manipulation of the embedded database works perfectly.

*Now at the time of distribution, I want to install the same software on another computer but with the same database structure that I created during development*

to achieve this, I've done the following

**1. I updated the method that gives me the connection object**

```
// Get a connection that is connected with the offline database
private static synchronized Connection openLocalDbConnection(){
    
   String connectionString = "jdbc:derby:db_name";
  
   Connection connection = null;
   
   try{
       
         // this time I'm using derby embedded driver
         String  driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
         Class.forName(driver);
         
         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.put("username", "user");
         props.put("password", "password"); 
         
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString,props);
         
       
   }catch(SQLException ex){
       ex.printStackTrace(); 
       System.err.println("At Opening database SQLException" + ex.getMessage());
       System.err.println("At Opening database " + ex.getErrorCode());
      
   }catch(ClassNotFoundException  e){
       e.printStackTrace();
     
   }
   
   return connection;
}
```

**2. I create the Setup of the app in netbeans with InnoDb**

**3. I install the app in the second computer**

**4. Copy the database to the second computer**

After I install the application in the second computer, I copy the embedded database that was generated during development and I paste in the application installation folder in the second computer.

**5. Launch the application in the second computer**

I launch the application in the second computer , and the app works just like expected, the manipulation of the database, everything works fine.

**PROBLEM**

Now after the user of the second computer uses the app for some time, he reports that , he can no longer have access to the application.

To figure out the problem , I went through some steps :

- I started by copying the database folder from the second computer and pasting it back in my development computer
- I put the database in my project folder then I launch the app trying to access the database using derby **EmbeddedDriver**

Following the above process I discovered that my method is now throwing an exception

```
SQL Exception: Failed to start database 'db_name', see the next exception for details.
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Util.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Util.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Util.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(EmbedConnection.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.bootDatabase(EmbedConnection.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(EmbedConnection.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection20.<init>(EmbedConnection20.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(EmbedConnection30.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver30.getNewEmbedConnection(Driver30.java)
 [java]     at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver169.connect(Driver169.java)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
 [java]     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
 [java]     at inppsecretary.databases.DatabaseHelper.openLocalDbConnection(DatabaseHelper.java:338)
 [java]     at inppsecretary.databases.DatabaseHelper.openLocalConnectionInstance(DatabaseHelper.java:302)
 [java]     at inppsecretary.databases.DatabaseHelper.<clinit>(DatabaseHelper.java:41)Call Ends
 [java] 
 [java] Task Succeeded  at inppsecretary.databases.DatabaseRepository.getUser(DatabaseRepository.java:46)
 [java] 
 [java]     at inppsecretary.controllers.LoginController$2.call(LoginController.java:130)Task Ended
 [java] 
 [java]     at inppsecretary.controllers.LoginController$2.call(LoginController.java:116)
 [java]     at javafx.concurrent.Task$TaskCallable.call(Task.java:1423)
 [java]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 [java]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 [java] At Opening database SQLExceptionFailed to start database 'db_name', see the next exception for details.
 [java] At Opening database 40000
```

- Further , to make sure of the problem, I copy the same database folder , I copy it in derby_database folder so that I can access from netbeans using Java DB, then I update my method to use derby **ClientDriver**. This time I can launch the application and it works.

My main concern is I can no longer have access to that same database folder using **EmbeddedDriver** , what can be the reason of such behaviour, and what can I do to prevent it.

Comment: I don't think that two JVMs can access the same embedded database at the same time. Is that the case with you?

Comment: well, I don't think that's the case, they are accessed from different locations. When I'm accessing using the EmbeddedDriver, the database folder is inside my project whereas when I access using the CliendDriver the database folder is inside derby_database folder.

Comment: When it says, "see the next exception for details", follow these instructions: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/derby/unwindExceptionChain